# Куча ошибок при создании многофайлового проекта

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь написать курсовую, но проблема с объявлением функций в другом .срр файле.

Главный файл.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ostream>
#include "functions.h"
using namespace std;
string path("Card_Base.txt");

int main()
{
  SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
  SetConsoleCP(1251);

  int choose;
  while (1) {
    cout << "1. Створити картку" << endl;
    cout << "2. Видалити крартку" << endl;
    cout << "3. Вивисти картку" << endl;
    cout << "0. Вихiд" << endl;
    cout << "Що робимо?: ";
    cin >> choose;  
    switch (choose) {
      case 1: system("cls"); NewCard(); break;
      case 2: system("cls"); break;
      case 3: system("cls"); break;
      case 0: return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Файл объявления функций (functions.h)

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

void NewCard();
```

Файл, в котором проблемы (Options.cpp)

```
#include "functions.h"
void NewCard()
{
  int numCard(256);
  string str;
  ofstream fout(path, ios::app);
  if (!fout) {
    cout << "Error";
  }
  {
    fout << "ID№" << numCard;
  }
  fout.close();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Options.cpp нужно либо добавить:

```
using namespace std;
```

Либо уточнить пространство имён:

```
void NewCard()
{
    int numCard(256);
    std::string str;
    std::ofstream fout(path, std::ios::app);
    if (!fout) {
        std::cout << "Error";
    }
    {
        fout << "ID№" << numCard;
    }
    fout.close();
}
```

Второй вариант предпочтительнее.

Помимо этого в Options.cpp стоит написать:

```
extern std::string path;
```

Это связано с тем, что из данного файла не видно объявленную вами глобальную переменную.

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало